# How do I add my project from Android Studio to my GitHub page?

Tags: android, git, bash, github, android-studio

I've been looking at some guides on how to do this but nothing I've tried is working.  What I've done so far:

- Downloaded git for windows
- enabled version control in android studio -> selected git -> pointed it to git.exe
- hit 'Test', everything works fine

This is when I get confused. I now have to add the remote manually through git bash, so I open up a bash prompt and I'm not sure what to type there.  I've tried things like:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/[username]/[projectname].git`
`git remote add origin git@github.com:[username]/[projectname].git`
for both of these I get the error message "fatal: remote origin already exists"

If these already exist then why do I not see the project listed on my github account? I've tried to do an initial push through android studio but I still don't see anything. Also, when I push through android studio it is as if everything is fine, I get no error messages.

Comment: have you tried using VCS -> Import into Version Control -> Share Project on GitHub? May be a simpler approach.

Comment: I have, but it seems like that doesn't give me the push/pull functionality. It is only a one way and one time thing.

Comment: That functionality does work doing it like that. It sets up the remote and everything and you can commit+push your changes. You got it working now though anyway.

Comment: for those who see this topic in future : this topic explain this issue
https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwii.logdown.com%2Fposts%2F2013%2F11%2F15%2Fandroid-studio-git-tutorial&ei=g-UKVbGUI4OtUYj4gKgL&usg=AFQjCNH838mjz0oCvJSBliofYKhpvPivSA&bvm=bv.88528373,d.d24

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have origin as a remote created already, just add your stuff to the staging area using `git add .` then use `git commit -m 'your commit message'` to commit your changes, then the most important part, ***PUSH*** your master branch to your remote using `git push origin master`.

You should read about the git workflow, here: [http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics](http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html), http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html.

Comment: Got it! It looks like I had to do one `git add` through the bash prompt so it would allow me to enter my github credentials. From then on it is working within Android Studio.

I do have a decent understanding of the workflow and how to use git. But I can definitely improve on that.  Thanks for those references!

Answer (score 0):

1 Sign up and create a GitHub account in www.github.com.

2 Create the repository to add project

3 In Android studio
  Go to VCS =>Enable the version control

Now the whole project will be red

4 Go to terminal

5 Type command  'git status' 
  to check the project files status,
  now it show all files need to commit

6 'git add .' to add all files to current push

7 'git commit -m"your message for push"' 
  Message for the push

8  Set remote for the push  VCS=>Git=>Remotes (Where to push )

9 'git pull'  to get latest code from server, for now skip this

10     'git push --set-upstream origin master'  command to push

11 Add your credentials in authentication

Now your project is successfully uploaded to GitHub