# Android Studio package files not adding or committing

Tags: android-studio, github

I'm trying to put my Android Studio project on Github for backing up purposes, and for some reason I can't add the files under com.*thing*.*otherthing* to the commit.  I can back up the layout files, the gradle stuff, and the built apk, but when I try to add the actual source code it reads "com.*thing*.*otherthing*" as one directory and does not copy any of the .java files inside to the Github repo.

Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23330865/2826147

Comment: use source tree so that you can maintain your code easily